# Keeping in sync dependencies of Makefile and Dockerfile

Tags: docker, makefile, dockerfile

Is there a way to somehow automate generating dependencies of docker file for Makefile or anything that would help me keep build system DRY. Currently I am using make to create docker images in following manner:

Makefile

```
dockerfile_deps = dep1 dep2 dep3

docker_img: Dockerfile $(dockerfile_deps)
  docker image build -t my_image .
  touch "$@"
```

Dockerfile

```
#some stuff here

COPY dep1 .
COPY dep2 .
COPY dep3 .
#some other stuff
```

This seems quite reasonable but everytime I add new dependency to Dockerfile I have to also add it to Makefile which is in my opinion against the DRY rule and makes the system prone to needless errors. Are there any existing solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you put all deps in the same directory and use a wildcard?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk it is possible but it still generates boilerplate if the deps come from different directories

Comment: That's way I said `put all deps in the same directory`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you don't seem to get me. I am saying that I would have to collect dependencies that were generated elsewhere and move/copy them to single directory. It's no good